# ADB on Kindles is there a way to receive a notification back when a window opens up or to see the checkbox status?

Tags: adb

I'm using adb event codes to setup and navigate thru over 200 kindles

```
adb -s %%i %*shell input keyevent 61"....
```

This works great for the first time thru but the second time thru, I could be turning off things that the prior run thru turned on or vice versa. Is there a way with adb commands to read status get feedback or otherwise check to see if a check box on the kindle has been set, or if a window pops up on the launcher screen.  I'm not understanding how to query the device to see if things are flagged or otherwise set. Thanks

Comment: What type of settings do you change? System settings? System settings can be queried using `adb shell settings get <settings_name>`.

Comment: i'm trying to set parental controls by stepping thru new kindles, routine works but second time thru I get prompted with the parental code and it just so happens the tab commands and enter commands (61,66) don't align with the popup box sequence where I only enter the code once. Looking for a way to detect if parental code is set, that would give me the option which ADB batch file to run.

Comment: adb shell settings get <settings_name>, pardon my ignorance here, but how do I find the kindle settings name for "parental controls"?

Comment: You can check if it is included in one of the namespaces: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/211989/2241

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you want, as this is enabling Wi-Fi on a phone instead of Parental Controls, but I think you can get some ideas from this example that might be useful.

Instead of blindly clicking on the switch that would toggle Wi-Fi ON and OFF, this only clicks if it is OFF

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient


helper = ViewClient(*ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(), useuiautomatorhelper=True).uiAutomatorHelper

obj_ref = helper.ui_device.find_object(body={
                                         'clazz': 'android.widget.Switch',
                                         'pkg': 'com.android.settings',
                                         'desc': 'Wi‑Fi'
                                         })
if helper.ui_object2.dump(oid=obj_ref.oid).text != 'ON':
    print('Switching Wi-Fi ON')
    helper.ui_object2.click(oid=obj_ref.oid)
else:
    print('Wi-Fi already ON')
```

[image]

It's using [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) with [CulebraTester2-public](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public) back-end.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however I'm not familiar with python, just the adb interface thru windows10 Fortunately, I have the Wi-Fi coded with ADB and it is reliable, I appreciate the help sincerely.